# Do getParamCached() and dynamic_reconfigure have the same functions?

Tags: ros-melodic, param-server, parameter, dynamic-reconfigure, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to reflect the changes in the parameters, in my node during run-time. In such a situation, which would be better to implement: getParamCached() or the dynamic_reconfigure package?

I know that the dynamic_reconfigure requires creating a cfg file. But getParamCached() can be implemented without any additional files.

So my question is if there would be a use case where dynamic_reconfigure implementation is advantageous over getParamCached()

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358225/do-getparamcached()-and-dynamic_reconfigure-have-the-same-functions?/) by [naegling77](https://answers.ros.org/users/54456/naegling77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2020-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way I understand it, they are totally different.

`getParamCached` provides local caching of values and gets notified once the parameter on the master changed somehow. However, you still have to call `getParamCached` regularly to get the notifications. I.e., you don't call it once in your constructor, e.g., and get all updates to the respective parameter.

`dynamic_reconfigure` however really provides the ability to change parameters dynamically via a callback based mechanism. So you don't have to call something regularly yourself, you just register the callback and this handles notifying you once a parameter changed.

Thus, I'd say `dynamic_reconfigure` is the way to go. `getParamCached` would probably work if this is really for a single parameter.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1